# Adding SSD data disk to Azure classic VM and moving PSQL database files to it

Tags: azure, ubuntu, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I use Azure infrastructure to host a Django/Postgresql application. The app and the db are on separate VM. Each VM has Ubuntu 14.04, and it's the **classic** flavor.

I've been using the OS disk for my db's storage (capacity: 30GB). This was fine in the early days when the size of my DB was small. But now, going out of disk space has become a real danger.

Via what steps can I procure more storage space for my DB VM. Moreover, what steps would I need to execute to move the postgresql DB to this newly procured storage space?

I want to avoid downtime or data loss, and being an accidental DBA of sorts, would love fool-proof steps explained in terms understandable for beginners. Thanks in advance!

---

**Update:**

After mounting the disk, the steps entail:

Editing the `data_directory` in `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf` to point to the new location (e.g. `/home/data/postgresql/9.3/main`)

Transferring contents of PG's data directory to `/home/data` via `sudo rsync -av /var/lib/postgresql /home/data`

Restarting posgtesql via `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`

Note: change steps accordingly if the additional storage is mounted somewhere other than `/home/data`

Comment: You're asking for data migration procedures? Might want to check with Postgresl documentation. As for mounting an SSD (premium) data disk: You'd need an `xS`-series VM for that (DS, GS, etc) - otherwise you can only mount standard storage disks. And if SSD is necessary, you'd need to migrate to a different VM SKU. This would be better suited for ServerFault, since it's not a programming question.

Comment: Hi, what is your VM size? Only S series VMs could mount SSD data. If your VM is not S series VM(such as DS) VM, you had better create a image and   create a S series VM by using new Portal. But it need downtime.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT: my VM is a DS series VM.

Comment: @HassanBaig If your VM is Ds Series, you could add SSD data disk to your classic VMs, please refer to my answer.

Comment: @HassanBaig It is normal output when you create Linux file system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, only S series VMs(such as Ds, FS) could add SSD disk. You could attach SSD disk to a classic VM on new Azure Portal. Please refer to these steps:

1.Create a new classic storage account(Premium). If you have Premium storage account, you could not create it.

[image]

2.Attach SSD disk on new Azure Portal.

[image]

3.Type:`Select Premium (SSD)` Location `Select your storage account`

[image]

Once the new data disk is attached, you'll need to create a filesystem and mount the disk. Assuming you're using `ext4` filesystem, here's how to proceed:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc
mkdir -p /home/data
mount /dev/sdc /home/data
df -h            #to view the attached disk
```

You could obviously mount it to a location different than `/home/data` as well.

Next, to ensure the data drive gets remounted in the event of a system reboot, do the following:

```
sudo -i blkid #get uuid for the relevant disk just added
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

And then add the following at the end of the file:

```
UUID=<uuid>  /home/data  ext4  defaults,nofail  1 2
```

E.g. it could be

```
UUID=753a5b1b-4461-74d5-f6e3-27e9ff3b6c56  /home/data  ext4  defaults,nofail  1 2
```

Note that `/home/data` is the drive you mounted the disk to, so change it as you like.

For a complete reference, go to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-classic-attach-disk#initialize-a-new-data-disk-in-linux

Comment: You could select one of them.

Comment: After you mount SSD disk to your VM, you could create file system to the disk and migrate your data to the disk.

Comment: Attaching a new disk does not need any downtime.

Comment: But if you want to migrate data, based on my knowledge, you had better stop your DB, then copy your data to the new disk.

Comment: Hi, this just a Linux issue. What file system do you want to use?

Comment: Just do it  `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc`  `mount /dev/sdc  /home/` It only an example, it depends on your needs.

Comment: OK, you could try to use `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc` create file system, then you could `mount` it.

Comment: Yes, select `y`.

Comment: @HassanBaig It is normal output when you create Linux file system.

Comment: Yep, just documenting it just in case. So now I can do `mount /dev/sdc /home/`. I have some files at `/home`, those won't be affected right?

Comment: No, you could not do it.

Comment: `mkdir -p /home/test` `mount /dev/sdc /home/test`. You could do a test firstly.

Comment: Mounted successfully. Thanks for the help, getting me this far!

Comment: Just `umount /home/test` and `mount /dev/sdc /home/data`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138504/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-hassan-baig).

Comment: Hi, you had better `mount /dev/sdc /home/data` firstly and then copy data.

Comment: Well I hadn't saved in data in `/home/test` yet, so nothing's lost.

Comment: I added `UUID=<uuid_here>  /home/data  ext4  defaults,nofail  1  2` to `/etc/fstab`. There seems to be no guidance on how to test whether the command was added successfully. But it's pretty straight forward, so I'm not too concerned. Should I just save and exit `fstab`, and that's it?

Answer (score 0):

At first, try to migrate your *classic* VM to ARM VM. The migration step is as follows; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-ps-migration-classic-resource-manager

Those steps seems long but *not* so difficult or painful. Migrating classic to ARM is optional but its strongly recommended as it gives more granual and flexible resource management including security configuration.

Then, (1) add additional disk to your VM and (2) setup mounted disk to your database storage.

(1) Add additional disk to your VM: It does not require downtime; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-attach-disk-portal?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2flinux%2ftoc.json

(2) Setup postgreSQL is out of Azure-related question, so I will omit the answer.